# Movie about an Arab/Bedouin boy who finds a buried spaceship at a desert

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this movie more than 20 years ago, so I guess the movie was shot between 1970 and 1999. The film was in the English language, but I don't know exactly which country made it. It was a live-action movie, not animation.

The movie was set in 17th or 18th century and it happened in a desert with some mountains.
I remember an Arab/Bedouin boy with his friend digging in the rock and pulling out rocks and finally a very large part of the ship was exposed to them.

Comment: Can you give us any more information? Live action or animation? What language was it in? Any other plot elements?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Can you describe the ship? Can you describe the boy/s? What were their names, what did they do with the ship?

Comment: You mention the Arab/Bedouin part. Do you know whether the boys were dressed in long robes? More close-fitting shirt and pants? Was it established that they were tending to herd, such as cattle or sheep, or if they discovered the ship while playing?

Comment: Was the exposed part of the spaceship reflective, rusty/corroded, organic, black (matte or shiny)?  How was it apparent that it was a spaceship?

Comment: I pretty sure the boy wearing kind of dress, but barely remember color or print.
They exposed the rear part of the spaceship. 
It is the only part i remember from the movie, i saw it many years ago.

Comment: at first I was thinking of the opening of "The Fifth Element" but doesn't really fit